# How to get ViewBag.Title without Title of Layout MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have set the title in my layout as:-

```
@ViewBag.Title | Web Clubbed
```

And My Index.html has Viewbag.Title as :-

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to webclubbed web developement & online marketing"; 
}
```

Now My title in Index.cshtml shows like :- Welcome to webclubbed web developement & online marketing | Web Clubbed

But I want to remove "| Web Clubbed" from title in Index.cshtml only. How can I do that?

Please HELP!!

Comment: erase `| Web Clubbed`?

Comment: please clarify your question to tell us *exactly* what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another viewbag value to store showing/hiding of the suffix.

Layout:

```
@{
  var suffix = " | Web Clubbed";
  var hideSuffix = ViewBag.HideSuffix as bool?;
  if (hideSuffix.HasValue && hideSuffix.Value){
    suffix = string.Empty;
  }
}

@ViewBag.Title @suffix
```

Index:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to webclubbed web developement & online marketing"; 
  ViewBag.HideSuffix = true;
}
```

You only need to set the ViewBag value if you need to hide the suffix.

Comment: Select ` | Web Clubbed` and press `Del` is the easiest way. lol

Comment: Did you even read the post?  **I want to remove "| Web Clubbed" from title in Index.cshtml only.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use sections to do this.

In your _Layout Page:

```
<head>
    @if(isSectionDefined("TitleSection"))
    {
        RenderSection("TitleSection", false);
        //Setting required to false
    }
    else
    {
        <title>ViewBag.Title | Web Clubbed</title>
    }
</head>
```

In your Index Page:

```
@section TitleSection {
<title>ViewBag.Title</title>
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem *I want to remove "| Web Clubbed" from title in Index.cshtml only.*??

Comment: The If statement will only be true if the section is defined. In other views where it isnt defined (Let's say an About page for example) it will go to the else block, which has "| WebClubbed" in it. If you define the section in the Index view it will render the section per the code contained in the block. This also useful when you want different meta tags for certain pages, for example

Comment: It says "isSectionDefined" does not exist in current context. When I'm using it in _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by comparing your RouteData Values to your view.

So in your `_Layout` page you can do a conditional statement like so:

```
@ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to webclubbed web developement & online marketing";

@if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "Index")
{
    ViewBag.Title
}
else
{
    ViewBag.Title <span>|</span> Web Clubbed
}
```

Now, depending on how many `Index` actions that you have.. you might need to make that conditional statement a little more specific..

```
@if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "Index" && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "/*ControllerNameThatIndexIsIn*/")
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Throwing Error for @ViewBag.Title | Web Clubbed - "Invalid expression term |"